# В каких случаях использовать JS для рисования графиков или картинок, а в каких PHP?

Tags: php, javascript, изображения, график, обработка-изображений

Приложение - простой фитнес трекер online для смартфонов. Нужно отображать статистику - строить красивые графики в браузере на странице пользователя.

Первый вариант - строить график на сервере и затем отсылать готовую картинку.
Второй варинат - отсылать значения и строить график на стороне у клиента.

Второй вариант нравится по следующим причинам:

- количество данных для отправки совсем небольшое и они уйдут быстрее, чем красивая картинка
- хоть функция построения не требует много ресурсов - хотелось бы видеть её на стороне клиента, хоть чуть-чуть, но разгрузить сервер
- самых разных библиотек с кучей настроек на js побольше, чем на php
- конечно есть вопрос безопасности - передача данных клиента, но я сомневаюсь, что кто-то захочет похищать фитнес-данные у начинающего разработчика.

В общем склоняюсь к тому, чтобы работать на JS, однако хотелось бы узнать - есть какие-либо моменты, которые могли бы склонить на сторону PHP в моём случае.

Из найденных теории знаю, что обработка картинок на сервере происходит только когда нельзя показывать код обработки (чтобы не своровали), либо когда обработка требует больших мощностей.

Comment: Картинка статична. С js графиком можно взаимодействовать. Код обработки у вас так или иначе будет на сервере. Сервер же отсылает информацию о точках графика

Comment: Генерировать картинку на сервере имеет в смысл в случаях: Капча( или нечто подобное) - что бы сложнее было взломать. Также график с историческими сведениями, которые не меняются, т.е. один раз сгенерировали картинку, сохранили на сервер. На клиенте она кешируется, нет нагрузки не на сервер ни на клиента.

Comment: stepan, мне кажется есть ещё множество других случаев. Например(не мой пример, просто на вскидку) - допустим вы хотите изменить фотографию так, чтобы она выглядела как рисунок в стиле импрессионизма и при этом не хотите, чтобы ваш js код попал на сторону. В этом случае тоже стоит использовать серверную обработку.

Comment: ArchDemon, получается на сервере делаем  всю статику, а то, что требует интерактивности - обрабатываем с js?

Answer (score 0):

На php реализовать будет сложнее. Если нет причин делать на стороне сервера по вопросам безопасности то js однозначно предпочтительнее. Работать будет быстрее, можно будет сделать графики интерактивными, трафик будет меньше.